# Does Firebase Realtime Database REST API support multi path updates at different entity locations?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the REST API of Firebase Realtime Database from an AppEngine Standard project with Java. I am able to successfully put data under different locations, however I don't know how I could ensure atomic updates to different paths.
To put some data separately at a specific location I am doing:

```
requestFactory.buildPutRequest("dbUrl/path1/17/", new ByteArrayContent("application/json", json1.getBytes())).execute();

requestFactory.buildPutRequest("dbUrl/path2/1733455/", new ByteArrayContent("application/json", json2.getBytes())).execute();
```

Now to ensure that when saving a /path1/17/ a /path2/1733455/ is also saved, I've been looking into multi path updates and batched updates (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes, only available in Cloud Firestore?) However, I did not find whether this feature is available for the REST API of the Firebase Realtime Database as well or only through the Firebase Admin SDK.

The example [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data) shows how to do a multi path update at two locations under the "users" node.

```
curl -X PATCH -d '{
  "alanisawesome/nickname": "Alan The Machine",
  "gracehopper/nickname": "Amazing Grace"
}' \
  'https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/saving-data/users.json'
```

But I don't have a common upper node for path1 and path2.
Tried setting as the url as the database url without any nodes (https://db.firebaseio.com.json) and adding the nodes in the json object sent, but I get an error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.

This would be possible with the Admin SDK I think, according to this blog post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html

Any ideas if these atomic writes can be achieved with the REST API? 
Thank you!

Comment: Interesting question. As far as i know this is possible for all the other firebase API's ([web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields), [android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields), [ios](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields), [c++](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/cpp/save-data#update_specific_fields) and [unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#update_specific_fields))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the updates are going to a single database, there is **always** a common path.

In your case you'll run the `PATCH` command against the root of the database:

```
curl -X PATCH -d '{
  "path1/17": json1,
  "path2/1733455": json2
}' 'https://yourdatabase.firebaseio.com/.json'
```

The key difference with your URL seems to be the `/` before `.json`. Without that you're trying to connect to a domain on the `json` TLD, which doesn't exist (yet) afaik.

Note that the documentation link you provide for Batched Updates is for Cloud Firestore, which is a completely separate database from the Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, the wrong reference to the root database.